# What is a reverse WWW shell?

Tags: http, shellcode

I'm having a hard time finding a good definition for a ***Reverse WWW Shell*** through regular Google searching.

So far, I've gathered:

> Reverse shell is a technique of establishing a remote connection
>   (shell prompt) to a host allowing only outgoing connections.

Am I close?

Comment: Do you have a source where you read that? The author possibly means a reverse shell that uses web technologies (e.g. PHP).

Comment: @Arminius It was in a computer science class, the teacher said it

Comment: The context in which it was said might have indicated what was meant by it, but likely a reverse shell in a web scripting language, perhaps executed via a web flaw such as remote file include. Or simply a reverse shell connnecting out on port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A reverse shell is a type of shell in which the target machine communicates back to the attacking machine. The attacking machine has a listener port on which it receives the connection, which by using, code or command execution is achieved.

[google search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse%20shell)

That being said a reverse shell could be done in many languages.  What your computer science professor is most likely talking about is the ability to upload a file to a web-server and then remotely execute it like a CGI script ... which in turn would give you shell access to the server.

- [first hit I found on github for php reverse shell](https://github.com/pentestmonkey/php-reverse-shell)
- [Cheat sheet
  of reverse shells in other languages](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet)